# Чтение квадратной матрицы из файла

Tags: c++

У меня имеется файл, в котором я записал квадратную матрицу через пробелы в виде

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Я хочу посчитать количество элементов, потом взять корень и получить длину строки и столбца. В конечном счёте переменная `count` содержит 10, а не 9 как я предполагал.

```
ifstream file;
file.open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\A.txt");
if (!file.is_open()) 
{
    cout << "Файл не удалось открыть. Название некорректно.";
}
double temp;
int count = 0;
while (!file.eof())
{
    file >> temp;
    count++;
}
```

После я перехожу к заполнению массива элементами. Но после заполнения массив содержит мусор. Это продолжение кода

```
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
file.clear();
int side = sqrt(count - 1);
int** A = new int*[side];
for (int i = 0; i < side; i++)
{
    A[i] = new int[side];
}
for (int i = 0; i < side; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < side; j++)
    {
        file >> A[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не проверяете успешность считывания. На последней итерации элемент не считывается, в потоке выставляется флаг eof, но счетчик все равно увеличивается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании стандартных библиотек С и С++, цикл с предусловием "eof" - практически всегда ошибка. Состояние "eof" в С и С++ - это флаг успешности *предыдущей операции чтения*. Это состояние не устанавливается само по себе просто при достижении конца файла. Это состояние устанавливается тогда, когда вы выполните [неудачную] попытку чтения *за пределами* файла. Вот эта последняя неудачная попытка чтения и попадает в ваш счетчик.

То есть в С и С++ для того, чтобы получить состояние "eof" недостаточно просто дойти до конца файла, надо еще "удариться лбом" в этот конец файла.

Явная проверка "eof" обычно нужна только для постфактум-разборки причин ошибочных ситуаций, а для управления логикой процесса чтения явная проверка "eof" не нужна практически никогда

```
while (file >> temp)
  count++;
```

В остальном коде: поставьте вызов `clear` *перед* вызовом `seekg`.

Также режет глаз неоправданное использование плавающих типов данных для решения чисто целочисленных задач. Непонятно, почему для изначального подсчета вы используете чтение `double temp;`, когда далее фактически будет читаться *целочисленная* матрица.

Comment: Большое спасибо. А не подскажите, что не так с заполнением массива?

Comment: Вообще-то наоборот, явная проверка `eof` нужна практически всегда. Иначе остановка из-за ошибки чтения будет расценена как окончание файла.

Comment: @Black Blur: В остальном коде поставьте вызов `clear` *перед* вызовом `seekg`, а не после.

Comment: @VTT: Переформулировал.